# VmWare Tools segmentation fault(core dumped)

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-tools

I am using VM player 16.2.4 build-20089737. My problem is VM tools does not installing on my machine, I am getting segmentation fault every single time. I cannot use shared folder, copy panel etc. even worse I have strange network problem , I think those are because of VM tools issue too. I can't do anything until fixed.. I did tried to restart VMware services and manually install open-VM-tools but did not work. I need help folks... Here is the information and logs ;

VM player version : 16.2.4
Operating system : Ubuntu 20.04
Kernel version : 5.15.0-46-generic

You can see the logs in below

```
The installer has detected an existing installation of open-vm-tools packages 
on this system and will not attempt to remove and replace these user-space 
applications. It is recommended to use the open-vm-tools packages provided by 
the operating system. If you do not want to use the existing installation of 
open-vm-tools packages and use VMware Tools, you must uninstall the 
open-vm-tools packages and re-run this installer.
The packages that need to be removed are:
open-vm-tools
Packages must be removed with the --purge option.
The installer will next check if there are any missing kernel drivers. Type yes
if you want to do this, otherwise type no [yes] 
INPUT: [yes]  default

A previous installation of VMware Tools has been detected.

The previous installation was made by the tar installer (version 4).

Keeping the tar4 installer database format.

You have a version of VMware Tools installed.  Continuing this install will 
first uninstall the currently installed version.  Do you wish to continue? 
(yes/no) [yes] 
INPUT: [yes]  default

Uninstalling the tar installation of VMware Tools.

The removal of VMware Tools 10.3.23 build-16594550 for Linux completed 
successfully.

Installing VMware Tools.

In which directory do you want to install the binary files? 
[/usr/bin] 
INPUT: [/usr/bin]  default

What is the directory that contains the init directories (rc0.d/ to rc6.d/)? 
[/etc] 
INPUT: [/etc]  default

What is the directory that contains the init scripts? 
[/etc/init.d] 
INPUT: [/etc/init.d]  default

In which directory do you want to install the daemon files? 
[/usr/sbin] 
INPUT: [/usr/sbin]  default

In which directory do you want to install the library files? 
[/usr/lib/vmware-tools] 
INPUT: [/usr/lib/vmware-tools]  default

The path "/usr/lib/vmware-tools" does not exist currently. This program is 
going to create it, including needed parent directories. Is this what you want?
[yes] 
INPUT: [yes]  default

In which directory do you want to install the documentation files? 
[/usr/share/doc/vmware-tools] 
INPUT: [/usr/share/doc/vmware-tools]  default

The path "/usr/share/doc/vmware-tools" does not exist currently. This program 
is going to create it, including needed parent directories. Is this what you 
want? [yes] 
INPUT: [yes]  default

The installation of VMware Tools 10.3.23 build-16594550 for Linux completed 
successfully. You can decide to remove this software from your system at any 
time by invoking the following command: "/usr/bin/vmware-uninstall-tools.pl".

Before running VMware Tools for the first time, you need to configure it by 
invoking the following command: "/usr/bin/vmware-config-tools.pl". Do you want 
this program to invoke the command for you now? [yes] 
INPUT: [yes]  default


You have chosen to install VMware Tools on top of an open-vm-tools package.  
You will now be given the option to replace some commands provided by 
open-vm-tools.  Please note that if you replace any commands at this time and 
later remove VMware Tools, it may be necessary to re-install the open-vm-tools.

WARNING:  It appears your system is missing the required /usr/bin/vmhgfs-fuse

Initializing...

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Making sure services for VMware Tools are stopped.

Stopping VMware Tools services in the virtual machine:
   VMware User Agent (vmware-user):[71G done
   Unmounting HGFS shares:[71G done
   Guest filesystem driver:[71G done


The installation status of vmsync could not be determined. 
Skippinginstallation.

The installation status of vmci could not be determined. Skippinginstallation.

The installation status of vsock could not be determined. Skippinginstallation.


The installation status of vmxnet3 could not be determined. 
Skippinginstallation.

The installation status of pvscsi could not be determined. 
Skippinginstallation.

The installation status of vmmemctl could not be determined. 
Skippinginstallation.

The VMware Host-Guest Filesystem allows for shared folders between the host OS 
and the guest OS in a Fusion or Workstation virtual environment.  Do you wish 
to enable this feature? [yes] 
INPUT: [yes]  default

The vmxnet driver is no longer supported on kernels 3.3 and greater. Please 
upgrade to a newer virtual NIC. (e.g., vmxnet3 or e1000e)


Skipping configuring automatic kernel modules as no drivers were installed by 
this installer.


Skipping rebuilding initrd boot image for kernel as no drivers to be included 
in boot image were installed by this installer.

The configuration of VMware Tools 10.3.23 build-16594550 for Linux for this 
running kernel completed successfully.

Enjoy,

--the VMware team
```

Answer (score 1):

> WARNING:  It appears your system is missing the required /usr/bin/vmhgfs-fuse

```
% sudo apt-get install git
% git clone https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches.git
% cd vmware-tools-patches
% sudo ./patched-open-vm-tools.sh
```

This should resolve the issue.

Failing that, uninstall rasa's and [install Ubuntu's](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=open-vm-tools):

```
apt-get install open-vm-tools
```

Comment: Drag and drop functionality is working now with those steps :) But network and shared folder problem still exists. Thanks James. I tried to debug all of the scripts and looks like problem related with kernel version. I recommend that,  do not upgrade vmware unless sure about maturity.